# jquery: Don't get why element selector work or don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html document with the following element

```
<input type="text" style="width: 40px;" name="rate" id="rate" value="1" />
```

Now I want to use jQuery to run a function once this textfield is changed. But I seem not to understand how the selectors work. Because this example works:

```
<script>
// works
$(document).on('input', function() {
    alert(); 
});
</script>
```

But of course it fires on all inputs that are interacted. So I only want a certain id to response:

```
<script>
// doesn't work
$(document).on('#rate', function() {
    alert(); 
});
</script>
```

But it doesn't work. Neither does it with class or attributes ("input[name='rate']") nor with 'input#rate' instead of document.

```
$('input#rate').on(function() {
```

Why is that?

jQuery included in head is:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wrap your code in `document.ready` handler.

Comment: `on` what? What is the event you are attaching?

Comment: [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Do not vandalise your post. This may result in a question ban. see [question bans](http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) accepts the event name as the first argument.

As there is no event called `#rate`, the following will not work.

```
$(document).on('#rate', function() {
```

Use

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#rate', function() {
               ^^^^^^^                         : Event name here
```

Comment: It seems likely that OP should continue to use the `input` event, rather than `keyup`.

Comment: @zzzzBov Probably, I'm just showing the correct syntax. The event name can be changed. :)

Comment: @JherekCarnelian If the element is added dynamically after page is loaded, the event wont' bind, if not, then wrap the code in `ready()` callback. See [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 2):

`on` should take event then `selector` like `.on('keydown', '#rate'`

Format like:

`.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`

so it would be

```
$(document).on('click', '#rate', function() {
                ^^^^^
    alert(); 
});
```

More on [Here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 1):

`input` in `$(document).on('input', function() {` is not a selector.

`document` is the selector, [`'input'` is the event type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input).

If you want to listen for the `input` event on a specific element, you can pass a selector as the [second parameter to `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler):

```
$(document).on('input', '#rate', function() {
//                      ^^^^^^^
  ...
});
```

or you can just select the specific element before binding the callback:

```
$('#rate').on('input', function () {
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have now:

```
$(document).on('input', function() { } );
```

means

> on every "input" event for any element do something

And if you want to do something only on particular element - pass this element as a selector:

```
$(document).on('input', "#rate", function() { } );
```

Here `input` is an event and `#rate` is an element selector.

Answer (score 1):

Correct way to make this work is :

```
 //on click
          $(document).ready(function(){
             $("#rate").click( function () {
                alert('Awesome');
            })});
```

for input box

```
<input type="text" style="width: 40px;" name="rate" id="rate" value="1" />
```

if you want to target class:

```
<input type="text" style="width: 40px;" name="rate"  value="1" class="rate">
```

script will be

```
//on click
      $(".rate").click( function () {
            alert('Awesome');
        })
```

for further info read :-
[jQuery Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp)

Comment: I am using jQuery here too, if you want to use document  put it inside
$(document).ready( function() { //put the code here });

Answer (score 1):

I find that when I am confused why a jQuery function isn't properly working the way I expect to consult the API Documentation for jQuery for usage and examples. Specifically for [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) I would reference the documentation page for that function:
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Each event is going to give a different desired outcome. You are wanting to fire off some code when the input is changed. The events used are based on vanilla JavaScript events so in this case your options would include on `change`, `keyup`, or `keydown`.

To decide which event to use for this, to me, it usually comes down to one thing: *Does my code need to check the input before it shows in the text field?*

You can see in this code how to use each event that I mentioned.

```js
// Using on-change
// You'll notice that this only 'fires off' when your cursor LEAVES the input field
$("#rate1").on("change",function() { $(this).next().html("<= Changed"); });

// Using on-keyup
// You'll notice that this only 'fires off' when the key you pressed is released, not when it is pressed
$("#rate2").on("keyup",function() { $(this).next().html("<= Changed"); });

// Using on-keydown
// You'll notice that this only 'fires off' when a key is pressed
$("#rate3").on("keydown",function() { $(this).next().html("<= Changed"); });
```

```css
.label { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" style="width: 40px;" class="change" name="rate" id="rate1" value="1" />
<span class="label"></span><br />
<input type="text" style="width: 40px;" class="keyup" name="rate" id="rate2" value="1" />
<span class="label"></span><br />
<input type="text" style="width: 40px;" class="keydown" name="rate" id="rate3" value="1" />
<span class="label"></span><br />
```

Something like `keydown` is best used when you're trying to see what key they entered before it goes into the input. I usually use this to see if the enter key was pressed.

Hope this helps!